# Why does my code give me the wrong result in python and different result even the same code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
bill = 0
if size == "S":
   bill += 10
if size == "M":
   bill += 15 
if size == "L":
   bill += 20
if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "S":
  if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "M" or size == "L":
     bill += 2   
if extra_cheese == "Yes":
     bill += 1  
print(f"Your final bill is ${bill}")
```

Welcomee to python Pizza Deliveries!
What size pizza do you want? S, M or L? M
Do you want Pepperoni? Yes or No? Yes
Do you want extra cheese? Yes or No? Yes
Your final bill is $16

> `your text?

Comment: Explain exactly what happens, what should happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "S":
  if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "M" or size == "L":
     bill += 2
```

The second `if` condition can never be true, because it is only executed when we already know that size is "S".

Comment: Welcomee to python Pizza Deliveries!
What size pizza do you want? S, M or L? M
Do you want Pepperoni? Yes or No? Yes 
Do you want extra cheese? Yes or No? Yes
Your final bill is $16                                                                                                                              # this output is wrong should give me 18

Comment: @AsmaaMansori Yes, and I explained exactly why that wrong answer happens.  I don't understand what more you are asking for?

Comment: ohh Sorry, now I understood what you explained to me,  so I changed my code  like this:                                                                 if add_Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "S" or size == "M" or size == "L":
  bill += 2

Answer (score 0):

```
bill = 0
if size == "S":
    bill += 10
if size == "M":
    bill += 15 
if size == "L":
    bill += 20
if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "S":
    """"Do somthing?????"""
if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "M" or size == "L":
    bill += 2   
if extra_cheese == "Yes":
    bill += 1  
print(f"Your final bill is ${bill}")
```

Comment: the problem is  python give the final bill wrong          Welcomee to python Pizza Deliveries!
What size pizza do you want? S, M or L? M
Do you want Pepperoni? Yes or No? Yes 
Do you want extra cheese? Yes or No? Yes
Your final bill is $16

Comment: u need to fix the indentation of if Pepperoni == "Yes" and size == "M" or size == "L":